# Quartz is bombarding the archive log of Oracle

Tags: oracle, logging, quartz-scheduler, archive

I am using Quartz to do schedule jobs, with JDBC Job Store. Most of the jobs are running every seconds.

Having turned on the archive log of Oracle database, I noticed Quartz is updating the related tables after each fire, including:

- insert into QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS
- update QRTZ_TRIGGERS for all fields (although I think the most relevant field is TRIGGER_STATE, START_TIME, etc)
- delete from QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS
- And, an unsupported action towards QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS (I don't know what's that)

Since most of the jobs are running every seconds, Quartz is then bombarding the archive log. it consumes 6 GB of disk space every day!

Is there a way to set the behavior of Quartz, not to update/delete tables after each fire?

Answer (score 0):

You can set QRTZ_TRIGGERS and QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS to NOLOGGING.

```
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_TRIGGERS NOLOGGING;
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS NOLOGGING;
```

Another solution would be to not run jobs every few seconds. Maybe persistent non-dying jobs are better in your case.

Comment: NOLOGGING likely won't help here.  If the database is in ARCHIVELOG mode, then REDO will be generated for every DML statement except an `INSERT /*+APPEND*/`, which I doubt Quartz uses.  See [this Asktom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869) for a table that shows when REDO is generated.